# is there a layer, that learns how to scale?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am looking for something like this:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape = input_shape)
# network structure
x = layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')(inputs) 
x = layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')(x)
#output layer
outputs = layers.Dense(output_size, activation='linear')(x)


#scaling layer??
outputs = layers.Scale(output_size)(outputs)


#build model 
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name = 'mymodel')
```

I want the layer to scale my outputs by a scalar. And I don't want to specify this scalar, but rather have the model learn this scalar by itself.

Is there such a layer?

Or can I achieve this with a Multiply layer in combination with something like sympy?

I need this for a quantum-computing model (made with tfq) which can only give outputs between 0 and 1. I can't use a dense layer, because that would bring in classical machine-learning, which I don't want to use.

Comment: I know this is probably not the most helpful comment, but why would you need this? Seems a bit overly complicated to me.

Comment: hmm, I have only a small network, and I am worried, that this network would take too long by training to reach high values.. So I thought maybe I can solve this with a scaling layer

Answer (score 0):

A scale layer is usually unnecessary because the desired information is in the relationship between the outputs.

If you want specific values, you probably need to change the loss function.

However, this link can allow you to make a personalized layer: https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/

Comment: Yes, thats true.. I updated the question. I need it for a quantum pooling network.
Thanks for the link. I just wanted to know, if there is already sth existing..